# How can I use numpy in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: python, wpf, numpy, visual-studio-2013

I have VS 2013 update 5, and installed Anaconda2-2.4.0-Windows-x86_64, canopy-1.5.5-win-64, IronPython-2.7.5. 
I create a new `IronPyton WPF Application`, and tested as generated by VS, running OK.
I added `Enthought Canopy 2.7 64 bits` and `IronPyton 2.7` as environments.
`numpy`, `matplotlib`, etc. are shown in `Enthought Canopy (2.7 64 bits)` when expanding *Python Environment* of the project.

After inserting the line `import numpy as np`, problem started (unabled to resolve `numpy`).

I looked for every posts and solutions for using numpy with VS, but no one solve mine. Here is my code, mainly as generated by VS, I only added the environments and the line `import numpy`.

```
import wpf

from System.Windows import Application, Window
import numpy as np  # inserted by me

class MyWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfIpyApplication1.xaml')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().Run(MyWindow())
```